# Has anyone decoded this message from Deus Ex: Mankind Divided?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

I recently came across [this post on Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42996/deus-ex-crypto-puzzle), and after some *heavy* research I haven't come up with an answer. The issue is that in Deus Ex: Mankind Divided, there is what appears to be an encrypted e-mail in the pocket secretary:

[image: Screenshot of the pocket secretary.]

From the game files, this appears to be the string:

```
FILE: client.pld31bf3856ad364e35.id
CecKIjBrWWr|9Vo2DN6DOWK|86lQSYxno0s|6c4yEcxnoGs|FxAgwKsaX0I|5LMLADBrWGr|SecLIdbTR04|FxAgwMbTQW4|9r2mtqyMtmX|AGVGov0nYGu|8zg5cz0nY0u|EX@DJoCyext|F#6XUkCyN0W
```

If you treat the pipes as column separators, we get 13 rows of 11 characters each:

```
CecKIjBrWWr
9Vo2DN6DOWK
86lQSYxno0s
6c4yEcxnoGs
FxAgwKsaX0I
5LMLADBrWGr
SecLIdbTR04
FxAgwMbTQW4
9r2mtqyMtmX
AGVGov0nYGu
8zg5cz0nY0u
EX@DJoCyext
F#6XUkCyN0W
```

However, this is where the trail often runs cold, though there have been many theories surrounding the e-mail; unfortunately, none seem to have been confirmed, nor denied.

---

Has anyone decoded this message?

Comment: There's the off-chance that this message truly doesn't mean anything and only "looks" encrypted by having jumbled characters.

Comment: Is the answer about finding someone with the key in Prague in the linked question valid? If so you'd have the plain text..

Comment: I'm not. I've never played the game, and I'm asking if the comment on puzzling (ugh, shouldn't have said it was an answer) valid...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no; the author of [the comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42996/deus-ex-crypto-puzzle#comment268482_42996) even states this at the end; though it's ran through a special Caesar cipher known as [ROT13](https://rot13.com/) (which is common on Puzzling SE to prevent spoilers in comments). If you decipher the ciphertext the author posted it says "*I'm joking, please don't downvote me to Hell*".

Answer (score 10):

Very hard to find out. We don't even know the set of character used to encrypt that message (if there's a message behind it). It's not a standard [Base64 encoding](https://www.base64decode.org/) because of @ and # (I already tried every source of characters, btw).

So it must be a sub-set of Unicode, my guess is a *ROT-47 alphabet*. This, at least, contains every character used in the email:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

or maybe a custom set of Base64 containing those two symbols (as per @NickKennedy's comment):

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#
```

Now the hardest part: discover the encryption method used.

I had no luck with *Caesar's* cipher, I tried all combinations using a quick [Java program](https://replit.com/@pinckerman/DeuxDecryption?v=1), even with different alphabets.

Other methods like *Polybius*, *Delastelle*, *Atbash*, *Rail fence*, *Playfair* and even *Enigma machine* seem unlikely because we have both uppercase/lowercase letters, numbers and those 2 symbols.

So my guess will be on *Vigenere* cipher, since it was used for [another encrypted email](https://www.reddit.com/r/Deusex/comments/ll8wh/did_anyone_manage_to_decrypt_this_email_from_the/):

[image: Vigenere encrypted email]

But again, we may have the same problem: "where's the goddam key?". That enigma already had a big hint to solve the puzzle, since...

> the actual key to decrypt it was a sentence in the email.

I don't own the game so I can't investigate, but the key may be, again, under our noses...

Anyway, nobody has decrypted this yet in years, so maybe there's nothing to discover.

Comment: What about base 64 but with @ and # in place of + and /? Not that the resultant byte stream looks all that usable anyway…

Comment: @NickKennedy I tried writing a Python script using a custom base64 alphabet, but it keeps giving me an error because the string to decode contains @ and # (which are not in ASCII standard), and this causes an invalid padding.

Comment: Huh? Since when have @ and # not been part of ASCII?

Comment: @HongOoi d'oh you're right, I meant base64. But the problem remains, @ and # were not accepted by Python script (that invalid padding problem), since removing them it just says that the message is not a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: Just string-replace #@ in the input and then fill up with = until the length of the (non-whitespace) characters is divisible by 4? Then you can use a standard decoder. (I did this in a text editor, and the output looks like random garbage to me, so no idea if base64 gets you anywhere.)

Comment: @Caesar yep already tried that, and got nowhere. I don't think it's a base64 encoding.

Comment: I wondered whether the hex part of the file name was a key, but simple rotations and xors with the base-64 decoded bytes doesn’t yield anything.

Comment: @NickKennedy yep that could be a hint, I converted that in bits and tried to figure out something but no luck at the moment